# Why are pictures I download using the Nikon Wu-1a adapter fuzzy when ones I transfer via cable are clear?

Tags: nikon, file-transfer

I have a Nikon 5200 and use  wu-1a adapter to plug in the side of the camera and down load pictures to my iPad using the WMU app. Lately the pictures all are fuzzy? When I download directly to my PC using the cable the are totally clear. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide more information about your camera's settings when you experience this? Particularly, how are you saving the images? As lossless 14-bit raw files? As compressed 12-bit raw files? As large/fine jpegs? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

My experience of the Nikon wu-1a is that it doesn't download fullsize images. It will not transfer NEF images, and my recollection is that transfers a reduced size jpeg. Therefore, a detailed photo will lose a bunch of the details in transfer.